# How to map/config Thymeleaf's delimiter to parse JavaScript containing RegExp?

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

When Thymeleaf tries to parse a JS file containing a given `RegExp` like the following one it will fail:

```js
new RegExp("^[+]*[(]?\\d{1,4}[)]?[-\\s\./\\d]*$");
                 --           --
```

The problem is that the content between the starting delimiter `[(` and the corresponding ending delimiter `)]` is not parsable. Therefore, Thymeleaf throws an error.

I am looking for a way to overcome this issue. My intuition would be to map the delimiters on which Thymeleaf listens to someones which don't interfere with RegExp gibbersish, maybe something like that for the starting delimiter: `__[(`.

Is there any way to do this or can I do something else to avoid this conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to disable inlining for those lines of code:

```
/*[# th:inline="none"]*/
new RegExp("^[+]*[(]?\\d{1,4}[)]?[-\\s\./\\d]*$");
/*[/]*/
```

Comment: Thank you, great answer works like charm. Much better than my current solution escaping the parenthesis through codepoints.